# How to remove the last column from a CSV file using perl

Tags: perl

How can I remove the trailing `,` from each row?

Existing CSV file:

```
S.NO,NAME,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,       
1,aaaaaaa,66,88,77,55,99,       
2,bbbbbbb,55,66,88,99,77,
```

The code is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl


  use strict;
  use warnings;


 open my $inn, '<', 'a1.csv' or die "Cannot open file for input: $!";
 open my $outt, '>', 'a2.csv' or die "Cannot open file for output: $!";

foreach my $line (<$inn>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @data = split /,/, $line;
  printf $outt "%s,%d\n", $data[0], scalar grep /^GO:/, @data;
 }
```

My expected output CSV file:

```
S.NO,NAME,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5                  
1,aaaaaaa,66,88,77,55,99          
2,bbbbbbb,55,66,88,99,77
```

Comment: you just want to remove the last comma ?

Comment: @xiawi Yes, that's enough, or even removing of first line comma is also enough instead of all lines
like ::
S.NO,NAME,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5

Comment: Is it necessary to use `perl` or are you open to a simpler solution with bash commands ?

Comment: Perl IS a bash command! perl -npe "s/,$//" file.csv > new.csv

Answer (score 2):

When processing a file a line at a time, it is better to use `while` (which also reads the file a line at a time) rather than `foreach` (which reads the whole file before giving you the first line).

If you only want to remove the final comma, then there is no need to treat the file as a CSV file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $inn, '<', 'a1.csv' or die "Cannot open file for input: $!";
open my $outt, '>', 'a2.csv' or die "Cannot open file for output: $!";

while (<$inn>) {
  # Remove trailing comma on first line
  s/,$// if $. == 1;
  print $outt $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`munge_column_names` patch provided by [Tux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426120/tux). This makes up unique names for each unnamed column header.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV;
my @headers = qw(S.NO NAME S1 S2 S3 S4 S5);
my $csv_in = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'a1.csv';
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'a2.csv';
my $eix = "001";
$csv_in->header($in, {munge_column_names => sub { s/^$/"E".$eix++/er; }});
$csv_out->say($out, [@headers]);
while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
    $csv_out->say($out, [$row->@{@headers}]);
}
```

Comment: I ran the code with the input from the question above and it produces the output from question above. Anyone can verify that my code works fine. ––– Have you **once again** silently changed the input, or used an input different from the one in the question? Then I shall be extremely put out.